# Is it a hard brick?

Tags: android, bootloader, locked

I think I've bricked my device (Huawei G330, U8225-1).
I was adb pushing while I received a "push failed: no space left on device".
The phone boots in recovery, I've root but the bootloader is locked.

If I try to push an update to SDCARD/dload it says "no such file or directory",
if I try to adb shell it says "exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: Permission denied (13) -"

What can I do?

Comment: This is not programming related. Try android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.  Any time you get permission denied on a rooted phone you can usually force it to work with the 'su' command, but make sure you use extreme caution while running superuser commands!  I'd say you should head over to XDA where you can get device-specific help.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/